# Set Textbox Location to Mouse Location

Tags: vb.net

I got two Listboxes. You can drag items from one into another. If one of the items is dropped i want to show a Textbox at the location where the item was dropped.

```
textbox.Location = Me.PointToClient(New Point(Mouseposition))
```

That's what i found as a solution, but i doesn't work 100%. The y-Coordinate seems to be correct but it's way too much to the right.

Comment: @HansPassant : He is... Look at his code.

Comment: Try this and see if it makes any difference: `textbox.Location = Me.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)`.

Comment: Won't work correctly if the textbox is embedded in another control, like a panel.  Safer version is textbox.Parent.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition).

Comment: @HansPassant it worked. Thanks